# « Our American Sisters…» : traduction de « sister »

Tags: traduction, anglais

In this title, "*Our American Sisters: Women in American Life and Thought*" published in 1973, le mot « sister » prend des connotations spéciales, peut-être de nature plus ou moins religieuses. Je ne trouve pas d'autre traduction que celle de Google translate.

- Nos Sœurs Américaines : les Femmes dans la Vie et la Pensée Américaines

Ne serait-il pas plus exact de traduire par "*consœur*" ?

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cons%C5%93ur))  Femme membre de la même confrérie, ou exerçant la même profession libérale ou la même activité que d'autres femmes, et, p. ext., que d'autres hommes.

Quel autre terme pourrait mieux convenir que l'un et l'autre des deux déjà envisagés ?

Comment: "Consoeur" ne va pas passer, surtout pour un titre, à mon avis. Quelles sont les connotations que vous voulez retenir dans la traduction?

Comment: @Frank Je cherche surtout à savoir ce que serait une traduction exacte qui m'aurait échappée. J'ai ce titre dans la tête depuis très longtemps mais en anglais et de toutes les connotations que l'on attache à « sœur » en français aucune ne me semble appropriée. En particulier je suspecte une connotation religieuse mais « sœur » s'arrête en français au textes religieux,  à la langue des  sermons,

Comment: "Soeur" a en effet une connotation religieuse en Français, le mot est utilisé directement comme titre pour de nombres religieuses. Par exemple, "les sœurs des Saints-Noms de Jésus et de Marie". Pour ce qui est d'une traduction, "Nos Sœurs Américaines : les Femmes dans la Vie et la Pensée Américaines" me paraît tout à fait adéquat.

Comment: @Frank Oui, bien sûr, mais si « sister » like « brethren » peut se trouver en anglais hors d'un contexte religieux formel (Amish communities for instance), ce n'est pas le cas en français; ensuite ces acceptions particulières comme « religieuse » sont impensables dans ce contexte politique, social, et culturel tout à la fois, bien que des connotations religieuses de la sorte que l'on trouve aujourd'hui soient possibles (bro, brother, origine religieuse, ce qui n'existe pas en français).

Comment: On peut tout à fait dissocier "soeur" d'un contexte religieux en Français aussi. Par exemple: "Nous sommes tous frères et sœurs dans la lutte pour les droits de l'homme", "... les Européens et les Africains sont frères et sœurs dans la lutte contre le terrorisme..." (https://www.eeas.europa.eu/node/28382_fr). "Soeur" n'est pas réservé au domain religieux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans ce livre qui est classé en sociologie dans les bibliothèques le mot *sister* semble<sup>1</sup> employé dans le sens suivant :

> a word used by women to talk about other women and to show that they have feelings of friendship and support towards them. (*Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*, 2003)

> a woman related to another by a common tie or interest (e.g. adherence to feminist principles). (*Longman Dictionary of the English Language*, 1984)

> a woman who shares an interest with you, especially that of improving women's rights (Cambridge online)

Pour moi ces définitions correspondent tout à fait à celle du mot **sœur** dans la définition suivante :

> [...] c'est aussi le nom que se donnent entre elles des femmes qui appartiennent à certaines associations, par exemple la franc maçonnerie, (1867) ou à des mouvements de revendications féministes (après 1968) ainsi que les membres  féminins de certaines communautés... (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*).

Quelques exemples :

> Solidarité avec nos sœurs Américaines » ([Une députée française](https://www.lyonmag.com/article/124098/droit-a-l-avortement-revoque-aux-etats-unis-les-reactions-des-elus-de-lyon/50))

> On a volé la vie de nos sœurs. Discrimination et violence contre les femmes autochtones.([Site d’Amnesty International](https://www.amnesty.org/fr/documents/amr20/001/2004/fr/), Canada)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>  Je n'ai pas lu le livre.</sup>

Comment: Il y aurait donc un usage naissant inspiré du terme américain, mais il n'est pas attesté ; le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C5%93ur) donne une définition générale (C. − P. anal. ou au fig., littér. [Gén. avec une valeur méliorative] Personne ou chose liée à une autre par des rapports de ressemblance physique ou morale, de filiation matérielle ou spirituelle, de chronologie, de situation, etc.), mais les cas sous cette dénomination (compagnons, franc maçons, rois (peut-être), …) sont spécifiques et il manquerait une définition pour ce cas (mais il semble difficile à cerner). (1/2)

Comment: Il n'est pas clair que le féminisme soit entièrement le cri de ralliement, mais il ne serait pas envisageable de traduire autrement que par « sœur ». (2/2)

Comment: @LPH le Larousse cite l'usage (https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s%C5%93ur/73207): "3. Celle avec qui on partage le même sort : Elle était ma sœur d'infortune."

Comment: @LPH Je ne crois pas que ce soit un usage "naissant".

Answer (score 0):

Sans mieux convenir que *soeurs*, qui peut évoquer la [nationalité](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sister) commune, on peut penser à [*camarades*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/sister/612059) même si ça peut évoquer certaines références politiques. Autrement on pourrait omettre le mot entièrement (« Nos Américaines... ») de manière plus ou moins réussie...

Answer (score 0):

On n'utilise "consoeur(s)" que pour faire référence à des femmes exercant une même profession.

Bien que "soeur" soit acceptable/pertinent dans des contextes particuliers, on pourra éviter d''utiliser ce terme en le remplaçant par **homologue** plus neutre si la publication effectue seulement une comparaison sur le mode de vie et la mentalité des femmes, sans relation avec le combat feministe.

*Homologue : personne qui est dans les mêmes fonctions ou dans les mêmes conditions de vie, de travail, etc., qu'une autre*.

Comment: Il y a dans le terme « homologue » l'idée de correspondance d'un système à un autre, alors que dans le contexte de ce titre (Our American sisters…) ce n'est pas le cas.